# Can anyone recommend a .Net XML Serialization library?

Tags: .net, logging, serialization

Can anyone recommend a .Net XML Serialization library (ideally open source).

I am looking for a robust XML serialization library that I can throw any object at, which will produce a human readable XML representation of the public properties for logging purposes.

- I never need to be able to deserialize.
- XmlSerializer's requirement of an object having a parameter constructor is too restrictive for what I want.
- DataContractSerializer does not give enough control over the output (which is not particularly human-readable).

Any recommendations appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Does this mean you want to be able to throw objects at it that are otherwise not serializable using the built-in serializer. Ex. Objects that are not attributed with the SerializableAttribute, do not have parameterless contructors, setters, etc...?

Comment: For human-readability ... are you willing to consider JSON serialization? I find it much easier in general.

Comment: JoeGeeky - yes, I would like to serialize objects that are otherwise not serializable using XMLSerializer.

- Overslacked - the reason i would like to stick with XML is that this makes it easy to further manipulate the XML using built in .Net XML handling code - which I want to take advantage of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 that come to mind right away:

http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/yaxlib.aspx

Comment: Thanks! YaxLib looks like it will work great. Thanks for the info.  FYI - it has now moved to codeplex: http://yaxlib.codeplex.com/

Comment: Nice...  I didn't realize that!

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that YaxLib has some of the same issue I was having with the XMLSerializer (it needs a parameterless constructor, and I had some issues with stack-overflow exceptions due to recursion).

In the end I went with json serialization using a library called [**json.net**](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). I have been seriously impressed with this, and so far is has seemed way way more robust than any xml library i have tried, and very flexible too.  The code is open source, and very impressive too.  Kudos James Newton-King (the guy who wrote it). http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the XML using XLST.