# Custom type is serialized to empty element

Tags: .net, xml, serializable

I created a custom type for EmailAdres and used this type in a class called User:

```
    public class User
{
public string UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public int CompanyId { get; set; }
public EmailAdres Email { get; set; }
```

}

```
[Serializable]
public class EmailAdres 
{
string _adres;

public EmailAdres()//needed for serialization
{

}
public EmailAdres(string s)
{
  _adres = s;
}

public static implicit operator EmailAdres(string s)
{
  return new EmailAdres(s);
}
public static implicit operator string(EmailAdres s)
{
  return s._adres;
}
```

}

The User object is returned by a webservice but unfortunately the Email element is rendered empty:

```
<User>
<UserId>887339</UserId>
<UserName>Behhh, Joyce</UserName>
<CompanyId>6401970</CompanyId>
<Email/>
</User>
```

I presumed the implicit cast would do the trick.

```
public static implicit operator string(EmailAdres s)
```

Answer (score 1):

XML Serialization requires that a class must have a parameterless
constructor.

In addition, any class members that are not public are not serialized.
Methods are not serialized. And properties that do not have both a get and a
set accessor are not serialized.

Serializing nested objects is not a problem. Everything in .Net is an
object.

EDIT: chack this answer [.NET XML serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575232/net-xml-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed make the _adres property public. If you don't want to do that you can implement the interface [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on your custom class:

```
public class EmailAdres: IXmlSerializable
{
   string _adres;

   // other implementation stuff removed

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        _adres =  reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(_adres);
    }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks Rene, if I make the _adres public will it still be possible (using attributes eg) to render it like a single element:
<Email>adres@server.com</Email>

Comment: I don't think so. Feel free to ask a new question referencing this question and answer.